# Did English ever admit the 'to have X years' verbal phrase?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

This verbal phrase remains grammatical in Romance languages (eg: 'avoir X ans' in French).

Comment: This just makes me think of the movie "12 years a slave".

Comment: It's not ungrammatical, though it does sound old fashioned. What makes you say it is ungrammatical?

Comment: Agreed with choster. It's still grammatical today, though any use of it will sound affected and draw attention to itself (which is likely why the movie CandiedOrange mentioned retained the original title).

Comment: **X years** is not standing alone, it's always part of an **X years a Y** phrase.

Comment: Your question is confusing. You ask about **have X years**, but the example sentences are of the form **have been X years**. The word **been** is very significant.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. "John has five years left at school" is clearly fine, but those of us who don't know French don't know if that's what you're asking.

Comment: It was carded at the door and prevented from entering because it was underage.

Comment: I prefer the [first version](http://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/314738/1) of this question because it gives in English the thought or sense you're asking about, as opposed to just the words in a specific order. It's also interesting and helpful when answering to see the source from which your question arose.

Comment: @Lawrence Thanks. Please feel free to edit my post. I confused the title of this question (but which was answered helpfully below and so which I retained here) with the intended question, the latter of which I have posted [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/315221/50720).

Comment: @LePressentiment The second post looks like your original for *this* question, so I'll leave this one alone. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, I’m not sure that your example (have been) matches your question (have), at least not close enough for me to understand how “…have been X years' appears to imply that 'to have X Years' was grammatical …”

However, even if your example and/or your interpretation of its implications are not perfect, it does not render invalid your good question as it is posed in the title header:

> Did English ever admit the 'to have X years' verbal phrase?

My answer to that question is that modern English  actually does admit/have/use the ‘to have X years’ verbal phrase, although it has not been abbreviated into a fixed expression, as it has been in your French example, used to tell how old one is.

I have always interpreted “avoir X ans” in French as an abbreviated form of “avoir X ans **d’âge**" where the **d’âge**, being so well understood when responding to “Quel **âge** avez-vous,” was at some point in the past deemed unnecessary and omitted (similar to how in English “I am 62 **years old/of age**” can be and often is reduced to just “I am 62”).
(see [**here**](https://books.google.com/books?id=-zVEAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA406&dq=%22ans+d%27age%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv8Pah0c_LAhWIlB4KHd_gD54Q6AEIMzAE#v=onepage&q=%22ans%20d%27age%22&f=false) in ‘Choix de Chroniques Et Mémoires Sur L'histoire de France: Avec Notices ...” by Jean Alexandre Buchon, via ‘Google Books’ for some early examples of “ [avoir] **X ans d’âge**”)

Although the French have seen fit to omit “d’âge” in the specific case of using “avoir X ans” in discussing/telling one’s age, they also use the “avoir X ans” verbal phrase in other contexts, with the specific type of years mentioned (d’expérience/de service/d'ancienneté, for example), **just as in English:**

"She **has 25 years** [of experience/of service/of seniority."